# How do you organize pages in reporting services without using subreports?

Tags: reporting-services, reportingservices-2005

I have a report in reporting services which I designed by creating rectangles for each page. I then put all of the controls for displaying that report in the page in that rectangle. I've done this because I created my own "headers" and "footers" instead of using the built in header and footer functionality because I needed to put information in the header that is related to data in the attached dataset, which you can't do in their built in headers.

The problem I have is when I need to "insert" a new page into the middle of the document, there doesn't seem to be a way to "push" all of the following pages "down". For instance, let's say you have a report with 20 pages. Each page in a separate rectangle. Now, I want to select all of the rectangles from the 4th one down to the 20th one down. It takes forever if I start a selection near the 4th one and drag the mouse to the bottom waiting for the scroll bar on the side to scroll the page down.

Are there better ways of selecting everything from a certain point going down?
Is there a better way to organize a large report? I wouldn't mind using sub reports, but I think I'd end up with the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

One benefit you would get from subreports is that the report would not be so large anymore.  You can put each subreport in a rectangle and set their size them to a half-inch or less with cangrow set to true and they will expand out for you when the report is rendered.  I would be cautious about data access within the subreports.  It is my understanding that if you duplicate references to datasets in the subreports it can increase the number of calls to the database.

Has this helped?  Let me know if you want any clarification or if I have missed the question.

Thanks.

Frank

Comment: I'm displaying reports in local mode, and I've never been able to get subreports to work correctly. There is a callback to get the data for a subreport, which I've never been able to figure out. When ever I add subreports I get a runtime error, though it's been a long time since I've tried.

Comment: The other problem I have with subreports, is having consistent headers and footers. I create a fake header in each page of the report, i.e. I put a rectangle at the top of each page which looks like a header because you don't have access to all of your data in normal headers.
If I split the report into multiple reports, I'm afraid I'll have problems creating a consistent look.